# Biology (DNA electrophoresis with agarose)X

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, pcr, gel-electrophoresis

I'm researching a polymorphism using restriction fragment length polymorphism (RFLP) and gel electrophoresis.

After RFLP, I should see fragments at 141bp and 111bp, but I can not see in 2% agarose, what is your suggestion, dear friends?

Here is my gel recipe:

- TBE: 0.5% 75ml
- agarose: 1.5gr
- Voltage: 65
- Time: 1 hour

Unfortunately, I do not have the ability to change the methods.

Comment: Why can't you change the conditions? Anyways, fragments of 141 and 111 bp should separate in 1,5% agarose. Can you show an image of your gel?`

Comment: How are you visualizing the bands? Ethidium bromide or SYBR green or something? What does "1hr" mean, did you run it for 1 hour? Did you load a ladder to confirm that the band didn't run off.

Comment: When you say you "can not see" the bands, do you mean they are totally absent? Or is only one band seen?